# Calculated updates in one query

Tags: mysql

This query works for updating the field `this_count` with a count of the people that a certain user ($user_id) invited:

```
UPDATE table_one SET invitor_count = 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM table_one
      WHERE invitor = 
         (SELECT invite_name FROM table_one WHERE user_id = $user_id)
  )
WHERE user_id = $user_id;
```

Can I update all invitor_counts in one query? How can I do that?

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+
| user_id | name       | invitor    | invite_name |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+
|     215 | Susan B    | Alicia18   | Susan       |
|     217 | Alicia L   |            | Alicia18    |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What is your table structured like? Why can't you do: UPDATE table_one SET invitor_count = (select count(*) from table where invitor=user_id)

Comment: Can you explain your table structure a bit more? invitor and invite name contain the same type of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
      table_one AS t
  JOIN
      ( SELECT b.user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM 
              table_one a
          JOIN
              table_one AS b
            ON a.invitor = b.invite_name
        GROUP BY b.user_id
      ) AS grp
    ON grp.user_id = t.user_id

SET t.invitor_count = grp.cnt
```

Answer (score 2):

I think following query would help in Oracle, I'm not sure whether MySQL has NVL or there is some other function like it.

```
update table_one z
   set invitor_count =
          nvl((select count(*)
                 from table_one x
                 join table_one y on x.invite_name = y.invitor
                where x.user_id = z.user_id), 0)
```

Comment: I looked up, you must substitute NVL with IFNULL in MySQL

Comment: or `COALESCE()`. But `COUNT()` returns a number always.

Comment: I used inner join, so there may be records with no result, so the `select count(*)` can return null.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` never returns Null. It returns the number of rows, so it would be 0 in that case.

Comment: +1, I implemented the other solution. This looks good too. For NVL, is that a direct substitute for MySQL users? Just replace your code with IFNULL?  That's the reason I tried the other one first. Wasn't sure.